# Fortran if then and instruction all on the same line

Tags: fortran

I don’t speak Fortran, but am trying to recode a few functions from Fortran into Python. I can’t compile and link the whole original source (involves c libraries too) and debug the original.  But I’ve become stuck on a little piece an experience coder may be able to help with. Essentially, in the middle of the Fortran code we have an if statement with instruction but ALSO a “then” on the SAME line:

```
If (something) then instruction
Something
Something etc.
```

this is nested in a series of ‘if end if’ blocks.
I know the syntax of this is not recommended/allowed, but the program apparently ran fine.  My Python version does not, so this could be the source of my error.  So my question is; do I just ignore the “then” treat it as

```
IF (something) instruction
Something
Something etc
```

OR alternatively, should I be looking for a closing ‘end if’ in this situation?
Is that even clear what the problem is?
Actual code, as suggested here:
Line in question is:

```
if (t.lt.1.) then i=i-1
```

All indentation as published..

```
subroutine detpic(sen,der,i)
     dimension sen(100000),der(100000)
     logical detmax,derpos

     detmax=.false.
     do while (der(i).eq.0.)
          i=i+1 
          if (i.gt.39999) then
              return
          end if
     end do
     if (der(i).gt.0.) then
                    derpos=.true.
                       else
                    derpos=.false.
     end if
     do while (detmax.eqv..false.)
          if (derpos.eqv..true.) then
              do while (der(i).ge.0.)
                  i=i+1
                  if (i.gt.39999) then
                      return
                  end if
              end do
                  t=der(i-1)/(-der(i))
                  if (t.lt.1.) then i=i-1
                  detmax=.true.
                              else
              do while (der(i).le.0)
                  i=i+1
                  if (i.gt.39999) then
                      return
                  end if
              end do
              derpos=.true.
          end if
     end do
     return       
     end
```

Comment: It would be clearer with actual code.

Comment: Thanks Scott… coming right up…

Comment: The code addition did not show before I closed as duplicate; with this code there is indeed a subtle difference.

Comment: Thanks, @francescalus, yes this is a permutation I hand’t considered.  As for the linked question; well I do really know how it should have been coded; as you infer, my problem is how will it behave as written. I am surprised the original even works, but by all accounts it does and has been popular for 20 years.  Recoding into Python seemed a straightforward task until I started to bump into problems in the original code. (https://archive.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb.shtml)

Comment: Any `implicit none` in the module? Free form or fixed form? What is the file extension? You might be just assigning to `theni`

Comment: There are no implicit none statements, thanks no. ….Free-form, fixed form I don’t know.  There seem plenty of statements starting in different columns, but comments always start with C I believe not “!”

Comment: File exension F

Comment: I do with Fortran included a conditional function `x=IF(<cond>,<true>,<false>)` similar to a tertiary operator other languages have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement like

```
      if (t.lt.1.) then i=i-1
```

is a valid Fortran IF statement if the source is in fixed form (and only if in fixed form).  It is the same statement as

```
      if (t.lt.1.) theni=i-1
```

which is a conditional assignment to the variable `theni`.  This is yet another time where `implicit none` and using free-form source makes code a lot easier to debug and understand.

If free-form source this is not a valid IF statement or IF construct introduction.

More generally, no action statement, other than an assignment statement or pointer assignment statement, begins with the four characters `then`. Equally no statement other than an IF or IF-THEN statement begins with `if(expression) then`. Together, these mean that the only interpretation of an `if (condition) then something` (for non-whitespace `something`) is as an assignment or pointer assignment action statement in an IF statement.